# I'm currently try to develop the cyber attack map from MatthewClarkMay / geoip-attack-map, however this open source only show inbound

Tags: javascript, html, security, web, threat-model

Is it possible to add outbound traffic from the current headquarters (main location) in map.js?
https://github.com/MatthewClarkMay/geoip-attack-map

I just want it to show like this
https://threatmap.checkpoint.com/

I want it to display both inbound and out bound from the headquarters (main location) which already tried to edit from index.html and map.js but still doesn't work even with chatGPT.

I have noticed that the current code only displays inbound traffic to the headquarters (main location). However, I believe it would be beneficial to also visualize outbound traffic from the headquarters, particularly the traffic that sends data to random IP addresses, such as reverse shell traffic.